# Cannot access 'this' in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
class Question extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.randInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1);
  }

  question = {
    quest: questions[this.props.randInt].quest,
    answers: questions[this.props.randInt].answers,
    correct: questions[this.props.randInt].correct
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get value of randInt but I get an Error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'quest' of undefined

Comment: What is `questions` ? Also,  what are you trying to use the `question` Object for? When do you want to initialize it?

Comment: That's an object imported from external js file

Comment: instead of `this.props.randInt` do `this.randInt`

Comment: It still doesn't work and throws the same error

Comment: Also, `Math.floor(Math.random() * 1)` returns always `0`.

Comment: try `console.log(questions)`

Comment: Cristy, I tried and it logs whole object

Comment: try this just to make sure `questions[0].quest` the same for the others

Comment: It returned right value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's `this.randInt` and not `this.props.randInt`, it should be `this.randInt` everywhere.

`question` is a [class field](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), which is syntactic sugar for constructor code:

```
class Question extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.question = {
        quest : questions[this.props.randInt].quest,
        answers : questions[this.props.randInt].answers,
        correct : questions[this.props.randInt].correct
      }

      this.randInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1);
    }
}
```

Class field declarations go first in the constructor body. Since an explicit constructor is not needed here, it should be:

```
class Question extends React.Component{
      randInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1);

      question = {
        quest : questions[this.randInt].quest,
        answers : questions[this.randInt].answers,
        correct : questions[this.randInt].correct
      } 
}
```

With class fields, explicit constructor is needed only for synchronous side effects that previously occurred in deprecated `componenentWillMount` lifecycle method.

Answer (score 1):

you need `this.question` instead of `question`

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.randInt` instead. `randInt` is not a prop, rather defined on the class.

```js
class Question extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.randInt = String(Math.floor(Math.random()*2) + 1);
  }

  question = {
    quest: questions[this.randInt].quest,
    answers: questions[this.randInt].answers,
    correct: questions[this.randInt].correct
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the `questions` Object. Also `Math.floor(Math.random() * 1)` returns 0

Comment: questions={1:{
                quest: "fasfs",
                answers: [1812, 1837, 1864, 1899],
                correct: 1837
},
2:{
          quest: "fasfag",
          answers": [2,3,4,5],
          correct: 4
 }}

Comment: there's no `0` key on your `questions` object. Obviously it's going to error out.

Comment: Okay, i tried Math.floor(Math.random()*2) + 1 but same

Comment: convert it to string, since you're accessing the property on an object